# Integration over a second order tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, linear-algebra, integration, tensor-products, classical-mechanics

I would like to compute the mean value of a second order tensor $\mathbf{T}$
  expressed in planar cylindrical coordinates.

The mean value for any second order tensor is (reference [1] page 101) 
$$\langle\mathbf{T}\rangle=\frac{1}{\text{vol}\left[B\right]}\int_{B}\mathbf{T}\mathrm{d}V$$

where $B$ is a region in Euclidean space and $\mathrm{d}V$ a volume element in the appropriate coordinate system. I would like to evaluate this for a tensor
$$\mathbf{T}=T_{rr}\left(r\right)\mathbf{e}_{r}\left(\varphi\right)\otimes\mathbf{e}_{r}\left(\varphi\right)+T_{\varphi\varphi}\left(r\right)\mathbf{e}_{\varphi}\left(\varphi\right)\otimes\mathbf{e}_{\varphi}\left(\varphi\right)$$

which takes diagonal form in the planar cylindrical coordinate system. The radial basis vector $\mathbf{e}_{r}$ and the circumferential (tangential) basis vector $\mathbf{e}_{\varphi}$ are

$$\mathbf{e}_{r}\left(\varphi\right)=\left(\cos\varphi\right)\mathbf{e}_{x}+\left(\sin\varphi\right)\mathbf{e}_{y}\qquad\mathbf{e}_{\varphi}\left(\varphi\right)=\left(-\sin\varphi\right)\mathbf{e}_{x}+\left(\cos\varphi\right)\mathbf{e}_{y}$$

where $\left\{ \mathbf{e}_{x},\mathbf{e}_{y}\right\}$ is the cartesian basis. The inverse transformation is

$$\mathbf{e}_{x}=\left(\cos\varphi\right)\mathbf{e}_{r}-\left(\sin\varphi\right)\mathbf{e}_{\varphi}\qquad\mathbf{e}_{y}=\left(\sin\varphi\right)\mathbf{e}_{r}+\left(\cos\varphi\right)\mathbf{e}_{\varphi}$$

Since I am integrating over an area (planar cylindrical coordinates), the volume element is $r\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\varphi$. I integrate over a disk from $a$ to $b$, evaluating $\langle\mathbf{T}\rangle$ as
$$\langle\mathbf{T}\rangle=\frac{1}{\pi\left(b^{2}-a^{2}\right)}\int_{r=a}^{b}\int_{\varphi=0}^{2\pi}T_{rr}\left(r\right)\mathbf{e}_{r}\left(\varphi\right)\otimes\mathbf{e}_{r}\left(\varphi\right)+T_{\varphi\varphi}\left(r\right)\mathbf{e}_{\varphi}\left(\varphi\right)\otimes\mathbf{e}_{\varphi}\left(\varphi\right)r\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\varphi$$

The $r$ and $\varphi$ integration are decoupled, 
$$\begin{aligned}\pi\left(b^{2}-a^{2}\right)\langle\mathbf{T}\rangle= & \left(\int_{r=a}^{b}T_{rr}\left(r\right)r\mathrm{d}r\right)\underbrace{\left(\int_{\varphi=0}^{2\pi}\mathbf{e}_{r}\left(\varphi\right)\otimes\mathbf{e}_{r}\left(\varphi\right)\mathrm{d}\varphi\right)}_{I_{r}}\\
 & +\left(\int_{r=a}^{b}T_{\varphi\varphi}\left(r\right)r\mathrm{d}r\right)\underbrace{\left(\int_{\varphi=0}^{2\pi}\mathbf{e}_{\varphi}\left(\varphi\right)\otimes\mathbf{e}_{\varphi}\left(\varphi\right)\mathrm{d}\varphi\right)}_{I_{\varphi}}
\end{aligned}$$

I would now like to focus on the integral $I_{r}$ I rewrite $\mathbf{e}_{r}\left(\varphi\right)\otimes\mathbf{e}_{r}\left(\varphi\right)$ in the cartesian basis,
$$\begin{aligned}I_{r}= & \int_{\varphi=0}^{2\pi}\left(\cos\varphi\right)^{2}\mathbf{e}_{x}\otimes\mathbf{e}_{x}+\left(\sin\varphi\right)^{2}\mathbf{e}_{y}\otimes\mathbf{e}_{y}\\
 & +\left(\cos\varphi\right)\left(\sin\varphi\right)\mathbf{e}_{x}\otimes\mathbf{e}_{y}+\left(\cos\varphi\right)\left(\sin\varphi\right)\mathbf{e}_{y}\otimes\mathbf{e}_{x}\mathrm{d}\varphi
\end{aligned}
$$

After evaluating this integral, I obtain
$$I_{r}=\pi\left(\mathbf{e}_{x}\otimes\mathbf{e}_{x}+\mathbf{e}_{y}\otimes\mathbf{e}_{y}\right)$$

which after applying the inverse transformation back to cylindrical coordinates becomes
$$I_{r}=\pi\left(\mathbf{e}_{r}\left(\varphi\right)\otimes\mathbf{e}_{r}\left(\varphi\right)+\mathbf{e}_{\varphi}\left(\varphi\right)\otimes\mathbf{e}_{\varphi}\left(\varphi\right)\right)$$

There is something that feels deeply wrong about this, as I integrated out the $\varphi$
 -dependence in cartesian coordinates but re-introduced it through the inverse transformation. Also, from a continuum mechanics point of view, the result seems wrong. Coud you please point out to me where I go wrong and how I can evaluate this integral correctly?

[1] Gonzalez, Oscar, and Andrew M. Stuart. A first course in continuum mechanics. Cambridge University Press, 2008.

Comment: This is not a research level math question, but it is interesting, and I would love to answer the question on math.stackexchange

Comment: So can you move this to StackExchange? Otherwise, you are free to delete this question, I have made a copy of it to repost on StackExchange. Please let me know how to proceed.